# How to Setup a SecurityServiceProvider with Custom REST API and Success/Failure Handlers?

Tags: symfony, silex

I have an AngularJS front end being served via domain.com/index.html. My API calls are all in the same domain scope at domain.com/api/*. I want to enable standard username/password authentication. However, all I need the Silex back end to do is set the session up and return a 200 success or 401 failure status codes at login time. I found pieces of code from the silex, symfony2 docs as SO but just can't get it quite right. I basically setup my custom Success/Failure custom handlers to return the codes and apply them to the firewall. My "check_path" in the firewall/form settings seems to be the only real peace that's important.

And here is most of the code. Hope it's formatted well enough for you to help. Thanks!

app.php

```
// Setup sessions
$app->register(new Silex\Provider\SessionServiceProvider());

// General Service Provder for Controllers
$app->register(new Silex\Provider\ServiceControllerServiceProvider());

$app['security.authentication.success_handler.auth'] = $app->share(function ($app) {
    return new ChrDb\Security\AuthSuccessHandler();
});

$app['security.authentication.failure_handler.auth'] = $app->share(function ($app) {
    return new ChrDb\Security\AuthFailureHandler();
});

// Define a custom encoder for Security/Authentication
$app['security.encoder.digest'] = $app->share(function ($app) {
    // uses the password-compat encryption
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder(10);
});

// Security definition.
$app->register(new SecurityServiceProvider(), array(
    'security.firewalls' => array(
        // Login URL is open to everybody.
        // 'login' => array(
        //      'pattern' => '^/api/login$',
        //      'anonymous' => true,
        //  ),
        // Any other URL requires auth.
        'auth' => array(
            //'pattern' => '^.*$',
            'pattern' => '^/api$',
            'form'      => array(
                'login_path'         => '/api/auth/login',
                'check_path'         => '/api/login',
                'username_parameter' => 'username',
                'password_parameter' => 'password'
            ),
            'logout'    => array('logout_path' => '/api/auth/logout'),
            'users'     => $app->share(function() use ($app) {
                return new ChrDb\Security\UserProvider($app);
            }),
        ),
    ),
));

$app['api.auth.controller'] = $app->share(function() use ($app) {
    return new ChrDb\Api\AuthController();
});
$app->get('/api/auth/login', "api.auth.controller:loginAction");
$app->get('/api/auth/logout', "api.auth.controller:logoutAction");
```

Here is the rest of the relevant code:

```
<?php 

namespace ChrDb\Security;

use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserProviderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\User;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\UnsupportedUserException;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\UsernameNotFoundException;
use Doctrine\DBAL\Connection;

class UserProvider implements UserProviderInterface
{
    public function __construct($app)
    {
        $this->app = $app;
    }

    public function loadUserByUsername($username)
    {
        $this->app['monolog']->addDebug('WTFFFF: ' . $username);
        $stmt = $this->app['db']->executeQuery("SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = ?", array(strtolower($username)));

        if (!$user = $stmt->fetch()) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException(sprintf('Username "%s" does not exist.', $username));
        }

        return new User($user['username'], $user['pwd_hash'], explode(',', $user['roles']), true, true, true, true);
    }

    public function refreshUser(UserInterface $user)
    {
        if (!$user instanceof User) {
            throw new UnsupportedUserException(sprintf('Instances of "%s" are not supported.', get_class($user)));
        }

        return $this->loadUserByUsername($user->getUsername());
    }

    public function supportsClass($class)
    {
        return $class === 'Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\User';
    }
}

<?php 

namespace ChrDb\Security;

use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authentication\AuthenticationSuccessHandlerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\TokenInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

class AuthSuccessHandler implements AuthenticationSuccessHandlerInterface
{
    /**
     * This is called when an interactive authentication attempt succeeds. This
     * is called by authentication listeners inheriting from
     * AbstractAuthenticationListener.
     *
     * @param Request        $request
     * @param TokenInterface $token
     *
     * @return Response never null
     */
    public function onAuthenticationSuccess(Request $request, TokenInterface $token)
    {
        return new Response('Login was successful.', 200);
    }
}

<?php 


namespace ChrDb\Security;

use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\AuthenticationException;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authentication\AuthenticationFailureHandlerInterface;

class AuthFailureHandler implements AuthenticationFailureHandlerInterface
{
    /**
     * This is called when an interactive authentication attempt fails. This is
     * called by authentication listeners inheriting from
     * AbstractAuthenticationListener.
     *
     * @param Request                 $request
     * @param AuthenticationException $exception
     *
     * @return Response The response to return, never null
     */
    public function onAuthenticationFailure(Request $request, AuthenticationException $exception)
    {
        return new Response('Login failed.', 500);
    }
}
```

Here is the error I get when trying to call the /api/login url: curl -d 'username=z@z.com&password=test' http://domain.com/api/login , to get either the 200 or 401 response.

```
[2013-06-26 13:10:48] myapp.INFO: > POST /api/login [] []
[2013-06-26 13:10:48] myapp.CRITICAL: LogicException: The controller must return a response (null given). Did you forget to add a return statement somewhere in your controller? (uncaught exception) at /Users/guachiman/Sites/chrdb/vendor/symfony/http-kernel/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/HttpKernel.php line 135 {"exception":"[object] (LogicException: The controller must return a response (null given). Did you forget to add a return statement somewhere in your controller? at /Users/guachiman/Sites/chrdb/vendor/symfony/http-kernel/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/HttpKernel.php:135)"} []
```

Is there anything obvious I am missing that would cause this error? I don't know which controller it's referring to that is returning null. I feel like I may need to setup my entire own custom ServiceProvider but I was hoping just setting up the Success/Failure handlers would be enough. I'm pretty sure I just have issues with the login_path/check paths.

Comment: looks like the request to /api/login isn't processed by the security/firewall - try setting up a route for /api/login returning some response to be sure.

Comment: OK thanks I updated my question as well to ask an actual question. Will try that out.

Comment: You have made a mistake in the firewall configuration if the controller action configured for the `check_path` is actually called instead. You can see this in the FOSUserBundle for symfony2 standard where they throw a RuntimeException in the `checkAction()` of the `SecurityController`. link: https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Controller/SecurityController.php#L68

Comment: Thanks I was scouring github for some similar source code and your link seems to be similar to what I'm trying to do. I'll check it out and update the question. Really appreciate the quick feedback.